# Electron app with multiple build variants(additional features than base app) with changes in package.json changing everytime, How to automate this?

Tags: npm, electron, package.json

I am working on an Electron app that has a package.json file in the root folder. There are 3 build variants that we release for the same.

1. Base App
2. Base App + Feature1
3. Base App + Feature1 + Feature2

I am facing an issue since point 3 needs some npm modules that my Base app doesn't need. Hence there is a change in package.json file for each build variant. Here are my doubts,

- Can there be multiple package.json files which will build specific
  build variant?
- Can this be done using one package.json file, If yes, how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey, I am facing a similar situation, did you figure out a good way to organize your variant apps.

Comment: I maintain scripts for installing and uninstalling packages in my single package.json file and I also maintain multiple json files for running electron-builder to avoid packaging unnecessary npm modules